# mongodb translation for sql INSERT...SELECT

Tags: mysql, mongodb

How to simply duplicate documents from collectionABC and copy them into collectionB if a condition like {conditionB:1} and add a timestamp like ts_imported - without knowing the details contained within the original documents?

I could not find a simple equivalent for mongodb which is similar to mysql's `INSERT ... SELECT ...`

Comment: I'm not a MongoDB expert, but I was doing some research on this too, and my understanding is that you would have to read each object in a loop and save it to the DB again, setting any value (such as the ID, or the timestamps) before you save it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use javascript from mongoshell to achieve a similar result:

```
db.collectionABC.find({ conditionB: 1 }).
forEach( function(i) { 
  i.ts_imported = new Date();
  db.collectionB.insert(i);
});
```

Comment: It's not the similar in dynamics...that is the same as doing it client side in your app.

Comment: Indeed, but the question was about copying documents from a collection to another while adding fields in a similar fashion to `INSERT ... SELECT`. Even more, mongoshell being the main interface to mongodb and all queries being javascript, a javascript query can, in my humble opinion, be assimilated to a SQL one for a RDBMS.

Comment: Indeed, however JS is just another driver, it is by no means the main one it is just the one that comes pre-bundled with MongoDB, but yea, in case the OP got confused I thought I would state that the dynamics of this code is different to how it works in SQL, so many think that the console is somehow special when it isn't.

Comment: @Sammaye: But you can usually send a JavaScript command straight into MongoDB and let MongoDB execute the JavaScript without leaving the database. I do this sort of thing in a few places to avoid the overhead of roundtripping something from db to client and back to db. JavaScript is, more or less, MongoDB's SQL.

Comment: @muistooshort if you wanna cause 3 million other problems like lock saturation and write problems and contention yes you can eval JS within the inbuilt spidermonkey (or v8 for new versions) engine. I should stress though that is is not run "in the database" it is run on top in its own environment, it is merely on the same server. If you eval that you should be considered as already doing it wrong

Comment: @muistooshort The aggregation framework is an example of something that is run "in the database", evaling JS client side to the server is by no means MongoDBs SQL and is considered bad programming

Comment: @muistooshort It should also be noted that the JS lock is singular and global and that eval doesn't work on shards nor on secondaries in a replica set. Those are of course just some of the problems

Comment: @Sammaye: So the MongoDB people added something that is nearly useless without wrapping it in a big "don't use this for anything" warning? Seems odd to me but thanks for the heads up anyway.

Comment: @muistooshort JS is awesome for MR and MR is awesome if used right, but the way you use it isn't the right way. There are numerous warnings telling you of evals limitations on the doc page, or at least there used to be

Comment: should be .insertOne now

Answer (score 15):

I realise that this is an old question but...there is a better way of doing it now. MongoDB has now something called aggregation pipeline (v 3.6 and above, maybe some older ones too - I haven't checked). The aggregation pipeline allows you to do more complex things like perform joins, add fields and save documents into a different collection. For the OP's case, the pipeline would look like this:

```
var pipeline = [
    {$match: {conditionB: 1}},
    {$addFields: {ts_imported: ISODate()}},
    {$out: 'collectionB'}
]
// now run the pipeline
db.collectionABC.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Relevant docs:

- [Aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)
- [$out stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)
- [some important limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/index.html)

Comment: Worth noting that $merge stage is more versatile, and allow you to enter the docs to the same collection too, and some other benefits. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#output-to-the-same-collection-that-is-being-aggregated

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb does not have that kind of querying ability whereby you can (inside the query) insert to another collection based upon variables from the first collection.

You will need to pull that document out first and then operate on it.

You could technically use an MR for this but I have a feeling it will not work for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this works in the context of sequence generation
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the below aggregation methods.

1. To copy all the data within the table

> db.collectioname.aggregate[
> {
> $out:
> "newcollectionname",
> }
> ]

2. To Copy specific columns to the new table

> db.collectioname.aggregate[
> {
> $project: {
> col1: 1,
> col2: 1,
> col3: 1,
> },
> },
> {
> $out: "newcoltest",
> }
> ]