# Conditional Insert Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I Want To Insert Data In `Collection1` Depend On Data That Stored In `Collection2` 
but I don't know How Can I Do that in `MondoDB`?
I Want Something like This SQL Code:

```
insert into collection1 VALUES(...)  
WHERE
  ((select current from collection2 where id='1')+1)
    < (select max from collection2 where id='1')
```

How Can I Do That in `MondoDB`?

Comment: There are "No Joins in MongoDB". You can only act on a single collection at a time. Rather than just "pasting in SQL", take the time to "explain the problem" if you expect meaningful answers. However, post that as a "new question" because this just became unsalvagable. Especially with an answer provided because you didn't clearly state your case. No SQL here. Just "explain" the problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

See the code by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076715/eric) as [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13534743/3651739) to almost similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533352/mongodb-translation-for-sql-insert-select)

```
 db.collectionABC.find({ conditionB: 1 }).
forEach( function(i) { 
  i.ts_imported = new Date();
//write your logic here and insert modified document or a new document.
  db.collectionB.insert(i);
});
```

Comment: i don't want to copy data from collection1 to collection2
i want to insert data in collection1 depend on data that stored in collection2
see SQL Command PLZ

Comment: is there another way instead of using javascript?

Comment: You can create a new document or modify the existing document and insert according to your logic.Regarding languages mongodb have drivers for  number of languages http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/

Comment: I used javascript becoz mong shell supports it