# Is there a way of doing calculations in mongodb and storing them

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection called cases and inside cases I have an array of cases per company object.

So the structure is:

[image]

Is there a way in Mongo of adding things together and creating new entries. So for instance in my angular project I run through all of the cases and count all priority 1, 2, 3 etc and then run through it again and count it where the type is 1, then again and where the type is 2.

I then save it back into mongo like this:

[image]

** Hardware is type 1 and software is type 2.

Basically each of those is a loop through the data and count where the value is a match and then store the final count. So in total there are 89 Open cases and of those open, there are 68 hardware and 21 software.

I was wondering, instead of pulling all the information down and then doing loops to count the data and then returning it back to mongo, if there is a simple way of doing that in Mongo itself. So as soon as I load the data, it automatically runs through and calculates it, then stores it as variables?

If not then thats fine, I just want to make sure I'm using the best solution to do this.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb translation for sql INSERT...SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533352/mongodb-translation-for-sql-insert-select)

Comment: @Tschallacka Thank you for the response, I will take a look into it and let you know.

Comment: Is this like grouping based on a field? For example, you may need to group based on distinct values of a field (type OR priority etc.) and find their count. Am i understading correctly?

Comment: @vcode - Yes so I run through all the cases and work out the count for the distinct field values. so for instance:

if (cases[i].priority === 'Priority 1') { this.priority1++; }
if (res[i].priority === 'Priority 2') { this.priority2++; }
if (res[i].priority === 'Priority 3') { this.priority3++; }
if (res[i].priority === 'Priority 4') { this.priority4++; }
if (res[i].priority === 'Priority 5') { this.priority5++; }

Sorry for the messy output - Im not sure how to put the code as code in a comment field

Answer (score 0):

Handling large data on front end is never a good idea. You can use aggregation in mongodb for easier grouping.

```
function group(req, res){
    var group = req.query.group;
    var companyID = req.query.companyID;
    db.collection.cases.aggregate([
        {$match:{companyID: companyID}},
        {$group:{_id:`$cases.${group}`, count:{$sum: 1}}}
    ]).toArray(function(err, data){
        if(err)
            return res.send("serverError");
        res.send(data);
    });
}
```

Using this way, you can pass any field(priority etc.) and result is grouped on the field.

The result of above query would be:

```
[
{
    _id: 1,
    count: 5
},
{
    _id: 2,
    count: 5
},
{
    _id: 3,
    count: 5
},
{
    _id: 4,
    count: 5
},
{
    _id: 5,
    count: 5
}
]
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I currently do that but I wanted to check whether it could automatically store it in mongo, rather than having a read function and then another to write.

For my priorities call I use:

db.cases.aggregate([
    { $match: { companyID: 218 }},
    { $unwind: "$cases" },
    { $unwind: "$cases.priority" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {$toLower: '$cases.priority'},
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: { $gte: 2 }
        }
    },
    { $sort : { count : -1} }
]);